# Eclipse RCP View Tab Selection

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp

I am using multiple views to display multiple table viewer.
The working or functionality which I want is, when a user clicks on the views tab,
the required data depending upon the view should get populated in the table.

Is there any proper event to do this ?

[image]
I want to load data when user selects a particular view tab.
I have used these two event for loading this data

First -

getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(new ISelectionListener(){

@Override

public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection lection) {

}
 });

for this event selectionChanged() method of all views are fired and
loads data in all views .. !!

Second -

getSite().getPage().addPartListener(partListener);

```
private IPartListener partListener = new IPartListener() {
  public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {

  }
  public void partBroughtToTop(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  }
  public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  }
  public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  }
  public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {
   //writing code here to fill TableViewer
  }
```

};

for this, the data is loading while creating the views.

But, I want to load data in tableviewer when a user selects particular view Tab

Comment: Where is the table? A picture might help us understand.

Comment: Table are in each view. when i select a particular view then fill a data on selected view table

Comment: I am also looking after the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener` to listen for the view part to become activated. Use:

```java
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(partListener);
```

in your view part to set up the listener.

The `partActivated` method is called when the view is activated (`partBroughtToTop` also sometimes).

Note: You need to check that the part is actually your view as you will receive events for all parts.